# Get current logged in member user id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net web app and i have an issue when two or more users on the same network are logged in . I use a query to retrieve account details which sometimes retrieves the details of the other person logged in on the same network.

Example

John are Lisa are logged in with different devices and different account on the same WiFi.

Sometime Lisa's Account Details appear as John's details on his account and same happens to lisa.

This is an example of the query

```
  // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    // Retrieve profile Name

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string selectSql = "SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = (@UserId)";
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSql, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
        Label1.Text = myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

I am not sure if this issue arises from

```
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

, the query or i am not doing something right.

Thank you.

Comment: could you log the currentuser to see if it's the same for both user?

Comment: Do you have output cache enabled on the account details page? Make sure you can vary it by the logged in user

Comment: Check you web.config setting for authentication and also once try to get user like Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)

Comment: @simone both user have different UserID's which is a unique identifier

Comment: do you have a load balancer? I had similar issues with load balancer and sticky sessions

Comment: @simone i only use Gzip, could that be what's causing the issue?

Comment: @Jack I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

The object currentUser contains a property UserName. Try displaying that to determine that you have the right user is the first place.

Comment: @mathew when the user logs in it displays the correct information, but sometimes when the user navigates to another page or refresh , it temporarly displays the other users details. So i have the right user.  But i have no idea why it temporarly displays another users details

Answer (score 0):

Check the worker threads on IIS, they can become crossed and set all sessions to the same thread.  Usually if this happens, they will change to the last person to log in.

Comment: Thanks. I am now to Asp.net.  How do i check the threads on IIS?

Comment: @Jack log into the IIS server, navigate to the site, go into settings , and check worker threads.